# @PathParam is Null

Tags: rest, java-ee-7

I've been looking at this for two hours, but I don't see how the ***batchid*** variable can be coming up as ***""*** (empty String rather than null) in the debugger.

I have tried removing the @Produces/@Consumes annotations, but no luck.

I am using a linux command line POST that looks like this:

```
http POST http://localhost:8080/cr/feed/send-batch/550f9ef7-b586-4029-bf7d-4d0659a08707
```

Can someone spot my error?

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/feed")
@RequestScoped
public class FeedHandler {

    @POST
    @Path("/send-batch/{batchid}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendBatch(@PathParam("batchid") String batchid) {

    }
```

Comment: Can you post also the imported tags? Perhaps you use not checked annotations. Sth. like:
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

And I dont think you need the first '/' in the path :-)

Comment: import statements added.  Which '/' are you referring to?  The class or the method annotation.

Comment: Does the method needs POST? If you just need the PathParam you could also try GET.

Comment: GET doesn't get me any further :(

Comment: You were right about the imports.  javax.ws.rs.PathParam is the right source for PathParam.  My IDE pulled in javax.websocket.server.PathParam.  Blame it on the IDE :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your import.

You are using

> import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;

but you should be using

> import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;